# AJAX Post JQuery does not working CORS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Excuse me, 
I try to catch my guest and save it using javascript ajax post..

It is different host (between the js and php server).
This is the javascript:

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
    var myip = codehelper_ip.IP;
    var mycountry = codehelper_ip.Country;
    var myurl = document.URL;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"ip":"'+myip+'", "country":"'+mycountry+'", "page":"'+myurl+'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
</script>
```

And the server side code:

```
<?php

$ip = "";
if ($_POST['ip']) {
    $ip = $_POST['ip'];
}
$country = "";
if ($_POST['country']) {
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}
$page = "";
if ($_POST['page']) {
    $page = $_POST['page'];
}

//Start Save DB
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO blog_guest (ip_address, country, page) VALUES ('" . $ip . "', '" . $country . "','" . $page . "')";
if ($ip != "" || $country != "" || $page!= "") {
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("' . $conn->error . '")</script>';
    }
}
$conn->close();
//End Save DB
```

Error at Browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Comment: You aren't returning any JSON from your server

Comment: Just try to decode the json data in php file using this function. json_decode();

Comment: It is different host..Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` option is wrong. It should be a Javascript object, not a JSON string.

```
data: {"ip": myip, "country": mycountry, "page": myurl},
```

Also, your server script doesn't return JSON, so you should not have:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: Still not working, Sir. I saw the error like this at scribefire: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.  Is that is the problem?

Comment: If the server doesn't allow cross-origin AJAX, there's nothing you can do in the client code.

Comment: I have add 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: OPTION "); at guest-post.php, but still not working.. How to make the server allow cross origin ajax?

Comment: It should be `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")`

Comment: I have tried it before, and failed too. What is the problem, Sir?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have much experience with CORS. There are plenty of questions about it on SO, search for them.

Comment: finally, my script is working http://pastebin.com/pBE7ApyX http://pastebin.com/n91xLWam

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your data like this: `data=JSON.stringify(your data);`.

Example:

```
var d = {...}; # your dict.
$.ajax({                      
    type:'post',
    contentType:'application/json',
    url:type url here,
    dataType:'json',
    data:JSON.stringify(d),
    beforeSend:function(){

    },
    success:function(){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the ajax code with this and check.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'ip=' + myip + '&country=' + mycountry + '&page=' + myurl,
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not working, Sir. I saw the error like this at scribefire: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at myhost.com/guest-catcher/guest-post.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.  Is that is the problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } // or  data: "name=" + value  + "location=" + value
})
```

Comment: This has been flagged as low-quality. Perhaps you should format your code and add some explanation about what your code does exactly, or your answer could be deleted by the community.